# How do I change my Rails datatype to PostGres bigint?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rails-activerecord, bigint

I’m trying to run the following Rails migration, using Rails 4.2.4 and PostGresql …

```
class ChangeTimeInMsColInMyObjectTimes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :integer, :limit => 8
  end
end
```

but it results in the error below.  I

```
rake db:migrate
== 20160613195631 ChangeTimeInMsColInMyObjectTimes: migrating =====================
-- change_column(:my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :integer, {:limit=>8})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "time_in_ms" cannot be cast automatically to type bigint
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING time_in_ms::bigint".
: ALTER TABLE "my_object_times" ALTER COLUMN "time_in_ms" TYPE bigint
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
```

What’s the right syntax I need to use in my migration?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: What type is `time_in_ms` right now?

Comment: It is of type "interval".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't automatically convert an `interval` to a `bigint`. You can't simply cast it either so the suggested `using time_in_ms::bigint` won't work either.

The suggestion is partly right though, the usual way to manually sort out type conversions when changing a column's type is to use a USING clause in the ALTER TABLE so all you need to do is figure out which expression to use to convert an `interval` to the number of milliseconds as a `bigint`.

A common way to slice and dice time types inside the databse is to use [`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> **9.9.1. EXTRACT, date_part**
>
> ```
> EXTRACT(field FROM source)
> ```
>
> The `extract` function retrieves subfields such as year or hour from date/time values. [...] The extract function returns values of type `double precision`.

The *field* in this case is the part of the time you're interested in and `epoch` is probably what you're after:

> `epoch`
>   [...] for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval

`extract` gives you the number of seconds as a double so you'll have to convert from seconds to milliseconds yourself. Something like:

```
using extract(epoch from time_in_ms) * 1000
```

should do the trick. In a migration, that would be:

```
change_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :integer, :limit => 8, :using => 'extract(epoch from time_in_ms) * 1000'
```

or

```
change_column :my_object_times, :time_in_ms, :bigint, :using => 'extract(epoch from time_in_ms) * 1000'
```